# AWS SimpleDB getAttributes consistency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

The docs for the Java SDK for SimpleDB say the following regarding the `getAttributes(GetAttributesRequest request)` operation:

> If the item does not exist on the replica that was accessed for this operation, an empty set is returned. The system does not return an error as it cannot guarantee the item does not exist on other replicas.

I understand that I can use `GetAttributesRequest#setConsistentRead(true)`, but the docs for the operation don't mention that, and that comment above is worrying me. It seems to suggest that an item request will succeed, if you're lucky!

Is this just an omission from the docs? Am I guaranteed to get back an item using a `getAttributes` request if I explicitly ask for a consistent read? (provided, of course, that a previous operation successfully put/updated the item).

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you on SimpleDB rather than DynamoDB?

Comment: SimpleDB is a much better platform, in my opinion, for certain use cases. Automatic indexing of all attributes so you don't have to set up an index in advance (and pay for it separately). I don't mind my queries taking a little bit longer, the 10GB limit per domain is not an issue for me, and overall it's far cheaper and simpler to use. I use DynamoDB too though, for other situations where performance is more important.